# Linq to Entities - Group by twice - NotSupportedException

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq

I have a somewhat complex query with two groups, I want to get the total sale for each customer by date.

In this example I am getting them for today and yesterday
I am using LinqPad to test my query and also we are currently using VB.NET

This is my query:

```
dim todayDate = new Date(2016, 7, 25)
dim yesterdayDate = new Date(2016, 7, 24)

Dim forecast = SalesHeaders _
  .Join(Customers, Function(x) x.CustomerID, Function(c) c.CustomerID, Function(SHeader, Customer) New With {SHeader, Customer}) _
  .Join(SalesDetails, Function(s) s.SHeader.HeaderID, Function(sd) sd.HeaderID, Function(SHeader, SDetail) New With {SHeader, SDetail}) _
  .Join(SalesValues, Function(x) x.SDetail.DetailID, Function(sv) sv.DetailID, Function(x, SValue) New With {x.SHeader, x.SDetail, SValue}) _
                .Where(Function(x) x.SValue.Date = todayDate.Date OrElse x.SValue.Date = yesterdayDate.Date) _
  .GroupBy(Function(x) New With {x.SFHeader.Customer.AccountCode}) _
  .Select(Function(g) New With
  {
      .CustomerAccountCode = g.Key,
      .ForecastData = g.GroupBy(Function(x) x.SFValue.Date) _
                      .Select(Function(gg) New With
                      {
                          .Sales = gg.Sum(Function(x) x.SDetail.SalesQty),
                          .Date = gg.Key
                      }).ToList()
  }).ToList().dump()
```

I am getting an exception which seems to be coming from the first GroupBy.
 I am getting `NotSupportedException Unable to cast the type 'System.Linq.IGrouping2[[VB$AnonymousType_3 ...] to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[[VB$AnonymousType_2...]`
LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

I suspect because of the number of joins, the number of Anonymous types is confusing things.
I was thinking that I might need to do a Select before my first GroupBy, but I don't know what the Select will be.

When I place a `AsEnumerable()` call straight after the first GroupBy then it works okay, but that I susspect is because the AsEnumerable() is executing the query and so the GroupBys are happening in memory, not on the database.

I'm hoping some bright spark might be able to tell me what is causing the exception and why.
Hopefully you can come up with a better query them mine too.

Thanks :-)

Comment: First try to do this with navigation properties instead of joins. If you start the query at `Customers` you probably don't need the first grouping (although that's a guess because the joins hide the multiplicity of the relationships).

Comment: If you put the `AsEnumerable()` afte the first `GroupBy`, then the first `GroupBy` should be happening in the database server, as you can tell in LINQPad using the SQL tab. That implies the issue is the second nested `GroupBy` can't be parsed by Linq To Entities.

Comment: I will design my models using `Navigation Properties` and recreate my query to see if I can create a better one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, Navigation Properties where the solution for me - I should of listened to this post [Don’t use Linq’s Join. Navigate!](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate)

My requirements have changed and I no longer need the query I originally posted about. But here's a even more complex query that works with Navigation Properties, just goes to show how important they are:
This query gets the total sales by Customer, Week and Product Category

```
        Dim sales= context.SalesValues _
        .Where(Function(x) x.Date.Year = year AndAlso weekNumbers.Contains(x.SalesForecastingDetail.WeekNumber)) _
        .GroupBy(Function(x) x.SalesHeader.Customer.AccountCode) _
        .Select(Function(g) New CustomerWeekGroup With
        {
            .Sales = g.Sum(Function(x) x.SalesQty),
            .CustomerAccountCode = g.Key,
            .Weeks = g.GroupBy(Function(x) x.SalesDetail.WeekNumber) _
                        .Select(Function(weekGroup) New CustomerWeekCategoryGroup With
                        {
                            .WeekNumber = weekGroup.Key,
                            .Sales = weekGroup.Sum(Function(x) x.SalesQty),
                            .Categories = weekGroup.GroupBy(Function(x) x.SalesHeader.Product.ProductGrouping.ShortCode) _
                                                .Select(Function(categoryGroup) New CategorySalesModel With
                                                {
                                                    .CategoryCode = categoryGroup.Key,
                                                    .Sales = categoryGroup.Sum(Function(x) x.SalesQty)
                                                }).ToList()
                        }).ToList()
        }).ToList()
```